# Using a function to convert a String into a Tuple

Tags: string, function, python-3.x, tuples

Basically need a simple function to convert String into a Tuple.
So far I've tried various methods like this :

```
def studentinfo(info) :
    infotu = tuple(info)
    return(infotu)

studentinfo(aaa)
```

But it just comes out with errors. Someone please steer me in the right direction.

Comment: We don't know what your input looks like, nor what you want your output to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a function for this.

Even in your example, you are just wrapping a single statement.

```
myString="noob" 
print tuple(myString)
```

will print:

```
('n','o','o','b')
```

if you want a delimiter, use the split function to turn the string into a list and the use tuple() on the list.

```
myString="stuff1,stuff2,stuff3"
myTup = tuple(myString.split(','))
print myTup
```

will print:

```
('stuff1','stuff2','stuff3')
```

That said, your problem is as follows: **you are returning the tuple, but you are doing nothing with it.**

You need to change that last line to:

```
print studentinfo(aaa)
```

You also need to make sure aaa is a variable that actually has a string value

Comment: I need to use function for this task. Basically I need to take a string argument and the function need to create/return a tuple.     So for example if the user enters "1234 2 PX KP" I need to turn that string into a Tuple.

Comment: What do you want the delimiter to be? white space? Or do you want every character to be its own element?

Comment: White space. So for the example I gave earlier the format of the Tuple should be ('1234','2','PX','KP'). The solution that you gave me seems like that will do the job but I want to use a function for this.

Comment: so wrap it in the function. Like I said, everything should work. No one can really help you unless we have more info. Right now, it is either 1 of 2 things. You are doing something really dumb, like not assigning a value to aaa, or something outside of your code is causing the errors

Comment: Didn't even add the last print line. Such a stupid mistake. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Did accept your answer. Don't have enough Rep to up vote you though.

Comment: All good! Happy learning! In the future, the Docs are your friend. They have all the answers you could ever want.

Answer (score 1):

You assigned a value to `infotu` but tried to return `inftu`.

Aside from the simple typo, this should work as intended (assuming you defined `aaa` before):

```
def studentinfo(info):
    infotu = tuple(info)
    return infotu

aaa = "Hello world"
studentinfo(aaa)
```

returns

```
('H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd')
```

If you are intending to split the string at certain characters, use the built-in function `split` instead:

```
def studentinfo(info):
    infotu = info.split(' ')
    return infotu

aaa = "Hello world"
studentinfo(aaa)
```

returns

```
['Hello', 'world']
```

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out. So tired. I changed it but it says "name 'aaa' is not defined". My goal is that I want the aaa to be changed into a Tuple.

Comment: If you want to pass `"aaa"` as a string, you need to quote it.

Comment: Okay made changes to the code however it prints out "Hello World" instead of ('H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd')

Comment: That's strange—it returns a tuple for me, with both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Really weird. Still returns 'Hello World' as a string instead of ['Hello', 'world'] tuple.

Comment: Try pasting the code as-is into a new interpreter window.  Maybe you misspelled something, or there's an old definition lingering in the global namespace.

Comment: I got it now. Thank You for the help!

Comment: this is not his problem, his problem is that he never told python to print the value.